# pyQGIS - hide loading gml dialog

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Using pyQGIS, is there a way to hide the loading gml dialog when making WFS http requests via a plugin (for QGIS versions >2.4):

After running this statement the load dialog shows:

```
QgsVectorLayer(url, "location", "WFS")
```

[image]

I would like to hide this dialog in favor of using the QtGui.QProgressDialog instead, is this possible?